# Moving .plist from usb drive to local disk using applescript

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

I've been trying to figure this one out for a while now, and I've hit a bit of a wall.

I have quite a few Macs in my environment, and for inventory purposes I need to copy a file named "Department-Info.plist" from a USB Drive to the following location on the hard drive

```
Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Dell:KACE:
```

I've come up with a couple of solutions that I thought might work, and believe I'm on the right track. However, I'm not getting the result I'm looking for.

Below is what I've come up with thus far, but I need to complete this task:

```
tell application "Finder"
   activate
   set FileToMove to "VOLUMES:DELL KACE:Mac:Department-Info.plist"
   set FinalLoc to "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Dell:KACE:"

   copy file FileToMove to FinalLoc
end tell
```

I receive [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwH5P.png) when running this script:

I've also tried using this variation of the script:

```
tell application "Finder"
   activate
   set name of document file "Department-Info.plist" of folder "Mac" of disk "DELL KACE" to "Department-Info.plist"
   set FinalLoc to "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Dell:KACE:"

   copy "Department-Info.plist" to FinalLoc
end tell
```

However, this yields the [following result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KuGv.png).

I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction, or provide resources that I may have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the command `copy` assigns a value to a variable, it does not *copy* files

The correct code is

```
tell application "Finder"
    -- activate is not needed
    set FileToMove to "DELL KACE:Mac:Department-Info.plist"
    set FinalLoc to "Macintosh HD:Library:Application Support:Dell:KACE:"

    duplicate file FileToMove to folder FinalLoc

end tell
```

However consider that you might not have sufficient access privileges to copy the file.
In this case you need to use the shell to enter an admin password:

```
do shell script "cp '/Volumes/DELL KACE/Mac/Department-Info.plist' '/Library/Application Support/Dell/KACE/'" with administrator privileges
```

Comment: Thanks so much! this works perfectly. I decided to use the shell instead! thanks again!